# Como salvar uma imagem no banco

Tags: android-studio, sqlite

quero pegar a imagem do imageView salvar no banco e fazer com que a ultima imagem salva volte quando abrir o app

codigo para transformar a imagem em byte

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream saida = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,saida);
    imagem = saida.toByteArray();
```

byte para bitmap

```
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imagem, 0, imagem.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

eu fiz um teste com duas imageview, pego a imagem transformo em byte, depois de byte pra imagem e coloco na imageview 2, mas quando tento fazer esse processo pelo banco a imagem não aparece

Comment: O recomendável é fazer upload de imagem no provedor e salvar o caminho no banco de dados. Dai quando necessitar rever a imagem no app é só informar o caminho e redenrizar a imagem. É  o que faço. ..se quiser um exemplo...lhe mando.